# Python FileNotFound Error while looping through files from os.walk

Tags: python, for-loop, shutil, os.walk, file-not-found

I'm trying to make a really basic script to sort a screenshot folder: I want to copy all of the files stored in the directory into subdirectories by year and month, and remove the original files as I do so. The code I have right now is entirely functional for this purpose, but when run still gives this FileNotFound error because it's trying to act on one of the files that's already been copied and removed:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\PracticeFolder\\ffxiv_06122021_193007_114.png'`

I've verified that this file has been copied/removed already. The script is functional but I'd like to add some more code to create an output file recording what's been done and this error is roadblocking me a bit. I feel like I must be missing something very obvious regarding the loop. Here's the code I've written:

```py
import os
import shutil
filedir = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\PracticeFolder"

month_dict = {
    "01" : "01 January",
    "02" : "02 February",
    "03" : "03 March",
    "04" : "04 April",
    "05" : "05 May",
    "06" : "06 June",
    "07" : "07 July",
    "08" : "08 August",
    "09" : "09 September",
    "10" : "10 October",
    "11" : "11 November",
    "12" : "12 December"
}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filedir):
    for filename in files:
        #Storing the month and year from filename as a slice
            year_slice = filename[10:14]
            month_slice = filename[8:10]
            month_name = month_dict.get(month_slice)
            #\\ used to avoid Windows unicode errors
            old_path = filedir + "\\" + filename
            new_path = filedir + "\\" + year_slice + "\\" + month_name
            shutil.copy(old_path, new_path)
            os.remove(old_path)
```

Comment: you have to use `root + "\\" + filename` instead of `filedir + "\\" + filename` because file can be in subfolder and `root + "\\" + filename` gives correct path `filedir\\subfolder\\filename` but `filedir + "\\" + filename` gives path without subfolder and this is wrong path.

Comment: In what sense does using \\ avoid Unicode errors? Use shutil.move (instead of copy and remove)although you'll need to think about what happens if the directories formed by the *year_slice* component don't exist. Use os.path.join for portability and for correctly constructing the source and target filenames. Check the filename format in case there are files in the directory you're searching that don't match what you expected. Don't use os.walk for this - consider using glob which will be better especially as you'll be able to constrain the pattern that your files need to match

Answer (score 0):

The code shown in the question doesn't build pathnames correctly. Here's an improved approach:

```
from os.path import join, basename
from os import makedirs
from shutil import move
from glob import glob

filedir = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\PracticeFolder"

months = {
    "01" : "01 January",
    "02" : "02 February",
    "03" : "03 March",
    "04" : "04 April",
    "05" : "05 May",
    "06" : "06 June",
    "07" : "07 July",
    "08" : "08 August",
    "09" : "09 September",
    "10" : "10 October",
    "11" : "11 November",
    "12" : "12 December"
}

for filename in glob(join(filedir, 'ffxiv_????????_??????_*.png')):
    base = basename(filename)
    target_dir = join(filedir, base[10:14], months[base[8:10]])
    makedirs(target_dir, exist_ok=True)
    move(filename, join(target_dir, base))
```